# Is it possible to feed TYPO3's default stylesheet by Extbase?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.x

I have to prevent loading backgrounds by `style=""` attributes in the frontend but still need to be able to set up background images from the cms.

TYPO3 has a default stylesheet (e.g. `typo3temp/stylesheet_[hash].css?[timestamp]` for loading CSS registred by TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_myext._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE (
    .css {}
)
```

But is it possible to extend this css file from a Extbase Controller?

Unfortunately `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer` has not such a functionality.

I also tried:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['plugin.']['tx_myext.']['_CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE'] = 'body {display:none}';
```

But it seems that the `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Page\PageGenerator` generates the page before any content is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData` array, it will add any content to `head` section of HTML doc, just make sure that used index is **unique!** so you have two soultions:

- One is adding styles directly to head like:

  ```php
  $GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['tx_yourext_styles_for_action_foo_bar'] 
      .= '<style>body {background: orange;}</style>';
  ```
- second is the same technique but in better edition, let's say that you have dedicated `typeNum` - `1234` which generates stylesheet file for given page as a *standalone* stylesheet file, so you can just include it as usually:

  ```php
  $cssUrl = 'index.php?id=' . $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id . '&type=1234';
  $GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['tx_yourext_styles_for_action_foo_bar'] 
      .= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $cssUrl . '" media="all">';
  ```

Of course you can use any other combination ;)

Comment: The 1st solution brings back inline styles which I want to prevent. The second one is some kind of solution to create your own dynamic css- file which I like to prevent also. I like to see a solution where I can write directly in the default stylesheet.

Comment: There is no such functionality.